# Enterprise Library default connection is not define in ASP.net MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, enterprise-library

Enterprise Library default connection is not picking ASP.net MVC Core from AppSetting.json I'm getting below error

```
The configuration file does not define a default database.
```

> "ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection":
>   "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=CustomConfiguration‌​Provider-D02F4CA7-9E‌​25-4121-BF38-195FCAE‌​674DE;Trusted_Connec‌​tion=True;MultipleAc‌​tiveResultSets=true"
>   }, "DataConfiguration": { "DefaultDatabase": "DefaultConnection",
>   "providerName": "System.Data.SqlClient" }

Comment: can you provide more info ? link for the EL you're using and etc ?

Comment: EL 6(https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.Data/6.0.1304) with asp.net core version 1

Comment: can you show how you have defined the default connection ?

Comment: "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=CustomConfigurationProvider-D02F4CA7-9E25-4121-BF38-195FCAE674DE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "DataConfiguration": {
    "DefaultDatabase": "DefaultConnection",
    "providerName": "System.Data.SqlClient"
  }

Comment: where you have defined this on your project ?

Comment: In ASP.net MVC Core Project appsettings.json file

Comment: you have to define it on `Startup.cs` file ?

Comment: are you following any tutorial?